# Python issue with redis hostname not resolved in docker

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, docker, docker-compose

I seem to have issues while trying to setup redis instance via python/django.  I have a lot of containers running in docker-compose and while other containers are able to connect properly, when trying with Django I get:

```
Step 11/16 : RUN python3 /home/allianceserver/myauth/manage.py collectstatic
 ---> Running in 749d9931dadb
[30/Oct/2023 08:59:47] INFO [allianceauth.eveonline.providers:181] ESI client will be loaded on-demand
[30/Oct/2023 08:59:47] ERROR [allianceauth.authentication.task_statistics.helpers:44] Failed to establish a connection with Redis. This EventSeries object is disabled.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 264, in connect
    sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
    return do()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 265, in <lambda>
    lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 595, in _connect
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allianceauth/authentication/task_statistics/helpers.py", line 41, in get_redis_client_or_stub
    if not redis.ping():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 1216, in ping
    return self.execute_command("PING", **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 533, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1086, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 270, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to cache:6379. Name or service not known.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 264, in connect
    sock = self.retry.call_with_retry(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/retry.py", line 46, in call_with_retry
    return do()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 265, in <lambda>
    lambda: self._connect(), lambda error: self.disconnect(error)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 595, in _connect
    for res in socket.getaddrinfo(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 954, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allianceauth/authentication/task_statistics/helpers.py", line 41, in get_redis_client_or_stub
    if not redis.ping():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/commands/core.py", line 1216, in ping
    return self.execute_command("PING", **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/client.py", line 533, in execute_command
    conn = self.connection or pool.get_connection(command_name, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 1086, in get_connection
    connection.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/redis/connection.py", line 270, in connect
    raise ConnectionError(self._error_message(e))
redis.exceptions.ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to cache:6379. Name or service not known.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/allianceserver/myauth/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 446, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 420, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 124, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allianceauth/authentication/apps.py", line 11, in ready
    from allianceauth.authentication.task_statistics import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allianceauth/authentication/task_statistics/signals.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .counters import failed_tasks, retried_tasks, succeeded_tasks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allianceauth/authentication/task_statistics/counters.py", line 9, in <module>
    succeeded_tasks = EventSeries("SUCCEEDED_TASKS")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allianceauth/authentication/task_statistics/event_series.py", line 21, in __init__
    self._redis = get_redis_client_or_stub() if not redis else redis
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allianceauth/authentication/task_statistics/helpers.py", line 44, in get_redis_client_or_stub
    logger.exception(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1481, in exception
    self.error(msg, *args, exc_info=exc_info, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1475, in error
    self._log(ERROR, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1589, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1599, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 1661, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/logging/__init__.py", line 952, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/allianceauth/notifications/handlers.py", line 14, in emit
    perm = Permission.objects.get(codename="logging_notifications")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 492, in get
    num = len(clone)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 302, in __len__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 1507, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 57, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 1359, in execute_sql
    cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 284, in cursor
    return self._cursor()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 260, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 244, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/utils/asyncio.py", line 26, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/base.py", line 224, in connect
    conn_params = self.get_connection_params()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 215, in get_connection_params
    if settings_dict["HOST"].startswith("/"):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

so I have tried to change name of redis container to see if it helps, I have checked that the networks exists and also other containers can connect without any problems.

```
  redis:
    image: redis:6
    hostname: redis
    networks:
      - redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    expose:
      - "6379"
    container_name: redis
    restart: always
    command: ["--databases", "1"]
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - '$USERDIR/docker/owncloud/redis:/data'
```

```
  allianceauth:
    hostname: "allianceauth"
    env_file:
      - .env
    container_name: allianceuath
    build: allianceauth/.
    ports:
      - '$ALLIANCE_AUTH_PORT:5555'
    volumes:
      - '$USERDIR/docker/allianceauth/conf/local.py:/home/allianceserver/myauth/myauth/settings/local.py'
      - '$USERDIR/docker/allianceauth/templates:/home/allianceserver/myauth/myauth/templates/'
      - '$USERDIR/docker/allianceauth/static-volume:/var/www/myauth/static'
    depends_on:
      - redis
    networks:
      - t2_proxy
      - redis
      - database
    restart: always
```

and the network:

```
  redis:
    driver: bridge
```

and configuration file:

```
## Every setting in base.py can be overloaded by redefining it here.
from .base import *

import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

# Django App Secretkey change if you want
SECRET_KEY = 'secret'

# Change this to change the name of the auth site
SITE_NAME = 'Alliance Auth'

DEBUG = False
# Add any additional apps to this list. Pre-Populated with some Apps
#INSTALLED_APPS += [
#'allianceauth.services.modules.discord',
#'allianceauth.services.modules.teamspeak3',
#]
# Teamspeak3 Configuration
TEAMSPEAK3_SERVER_IP = '127.0.0.1'
TEAMSPEAK3_SERVER_PORT = 10011
TEAMSPEAK3_SERVERQUERY_USER = 'serveradmin'
TEAMSPEAK3_SERVERQUERY_PASSWORD = ''
TEAMSPEAK3_VIRTUAL_SERVER = 1
TEAMSPEAK3_PUBLIC_URL = ''

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE['run_ts3_group_update'] = {
    'task': 'allianceauth.services.modules.teamspeak3.tasks.run_ts3_group_update',
    'schedule': crontab(minute='*/30'),
}
# Discourse Configuration
DISCOURSE_URL = ''
DISCOURSE_API_USERNAME = ''
DISCOURSE_API_KEY = ''
DISCOURSE_SSO_SECRET = ''

# SMF Configuration
SMF_URL = ''
DATABASES['smf'] = {Auth
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'alliance_smf',
    'USER':  os.getenv('ALLIANCE_AUTH_USER'),
    'PASSWORD':  os.getenv('ALLIANCE_AUTH_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST':  os.getenv('MYSQL_HOST'),
    'PORT': '3306',
}
#### ADD YOUR OWN LOCAL DATABASE DETAILS HERE
DATABASES['default'] = {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME':  os.getenv('ALLIANCE_AUTH_DATABASE'),
    'USER':  os.getenv('ALLIANCE_AUTH_USER'),
    'PASSWORD':  os.getenv('ALLIANCE_AUTH_PASSWORD'),
    'HOST':  os.getenv('MYSQL_HOST'),
    'PORT': '3306',
}


ESI_SSO_CLIENT_ID =  os.getenv('CCP_SSO_CLIENT_ID')
ESI_SSO_CLIENT_SECRET =  os.getenv('CCP_SSO_SECRET_KEY')
ESI_SSO_CALLBACK_URL = ''

VERIFY_EMAIL = False
EMAIL_HOST =  os.getenv('SMTP_HOST')
EMAIL_PORT =  os.getenv('SMTP_PORT')
EMAIL_HOST_USER =  os.getenv('SMTP_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =  os.getenv('SMTP_PASSWORD')
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL =  os.getenv('SMTP_FROM')
#######################################
# Add any custom settings below here. #
#######################################

ROOT_URLCONF = ''
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'myauth.wsgi.application'
STATIC_ROOT = "/var/www/myauth/static/"
BROKER_URL = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://redis:6379/0'
CACHES = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "django_redis.cache.RedisCache",
        "LOCATION": "redis://redis:6379",
        "OPTIONS": {
            "CLIENT_CLASS": "django_redis.client.DefaultClient",
        }
    }
}
```

```
docker network inspect docker_redis
[
    {
        "Name": "docker_redis",
        "Id": "7102a8377a62cdd6f976d8ffa74b32bf4c24b7466591e48afef921d1bb8b4f23",
        "Created": "2023-10-28T19:29:31.165029181Z",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.23.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.23.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "ac4128ce849b8cf3f95aeb4d355ef1d6f54df8f3af5670722869472ec8b33ff4": {
                "Name": "redis",
                "EndpointID": "7248959b6f37bd1e94378d333f6e0ac06cf63485716456d43c11506f01c21742",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "dc1202a1f426f9fb0d6be979c95ec208b6f34948a95c123e0d61f57593916768": {
                "Name": "owncloud_server",
                "EndpointID": "71b290e54f6fb04d14413b63d4f0dc629d34a38c3cf79b005b3602460da9635f",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "f5609ead697fccc6c5a640445165f2d2bc8885f41211f227d7a0c80b5bee5b25": {
                "Name": "pathfinder_web",
                "EndpointID": "736c5927343c80677f3b1c669eb3b62c068742e60a62281f671c45904bb434c5",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:17:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.23.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "redis",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "docker",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.25.5"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: post here all of your contents in settings.py file, (remove credentials and personal information)

Comment: thats all the config I have thats overwriting settings, rest is coming from the actual python package allianceauth

Comment: I will add steps you have to check first and update your post.

1). check your load_env , is it really loading env variables?

2) Is your redis container spinning up  successfully (even without django)?

3) if two above , works fine, write wait-redis.sh. file for django waiting to redis to be up to make connection.

Comment: connection fails on redis which doesn't have env variables, but yes they do load. yes redis is running as other services even right now are using it.  the Django app is a new service on top of the other services which are already running fine.

Comment: docker network inspect redis,   can you run and add response here as well?

Comment: and allianceauth.authentication.task_statistics.helpers:44. what  this line contains too

Comment: done @ElvinJafarov and here's the class https://gitlab.com/allianceauth/allianceauth/-/blob/master/allianceauth/authentication/task_statistics/helpers.py

Comment: During the image build you can never connect to another container.  The temporary containers the builder launches aren't on the Compose network.  I'm a little surprised the `collectstatic` stage wants to talk to Redis, though; is that something that can be fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After my research, I realized  that while building an image, it is not possible to establish a connection to another network due to Docker's creation of a temporary container for executing build pipelines. One way to fix this issue, you should use the host's IP address for connecting to Redis.

Nonetheless, as pointed out by David Maze, it is interesting  to explore the underlying reason why `collectstatics` tries to establish a connection with Redis.

Comment: using `172.17.0.1` rather than `redis` has worked in my case. yeah it is weird why they do it the way it is done. Will open a ticket with the package provider and see if it can be changed

Comment: although now that I have said it I am getting a timeout when trying to connect, wonder if its something with redis config now